# Determine if the extension is algebraic and find the minimum polynomial of the extension generator element

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have the following extensions:

$a)$ $\mathbb{Q}(X)|\mathbb{Q}\left(\dfrac{1}{X^4}\right)$

$b)$ $\mathbb{Q}(X)|\mathbb{Q}(X^2+1)$ and

$c)$ $\mathbb{Z}(X)|\mathbb{Z}(X^3 +2)$

Determine if the extension is algebraic and find the minimum polynomial of the extension generator element.

Comment: @DonAntonio I have to show that $ X ^4  t - 1 $ is an irreducible polynomial

Comment: @DonAntonio You meant $t^4 - X^4 \in \mathbb{Q}(1/X^4)[t]$

Comment: @reuns Indeed so. Thanks, deleting the original post...though the idea, hopefully, was clear to the OP.

Comment: @JucySantos In that case (read the third comment), that wouldn't be a problem as that is a lineal polynomial...Yet read what reuns wrote. That shows the extension is algebraic.

Comment: @DonAntonio $ t ^4 - X ^4 $ is not a linear polynomial in $t$.

Comment: @DonAntonio In the case, the polynomial in $\mathbb{Q} \left(\dfrac{1}{X^4} \right)$ that I have to consider to end the problem is $ X^4 t-1 $, which is linear , therefore irreducible, so the extension is algebraic ..